# Can I have Async task run on different thread other than background

Tags: android, memory-management, android-asynctask

I have several Async tasks throughout an app I'm designing.  Several times an async task will run very slowly.  Examining the log file shows that the desired background operation isn't actually causing the delay.  The delay is that the background thread is held up by the Garbage Collection (davlvikvm).  I'm not totally sure why there is so much GC happening in my app, it's not particularly memory intensive (no videos, just basic lists and a few images), and the MAT tool doesn't show any egregious memory violators.  Regardless, I'm looking for a solution to keep my app running quickly to avoid long delays for the user.

I have tried to force the GC to happen earlier to avoid it, but it still runs at these inopportune times.  My new thought is to tell the async task to run on a separate independent thread, so that it is not held up by the status of the GC.  Is this possible?  Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific solution to your problem, but no, running your workload on a different thread will not change the behavior of your application during GC.

GC essentially stops the whole VM while it's working. The Dalvik garbage collector (since Gingerbread) is designed to minimize the pause time, but it still stops the entire VM.

For a little more detail, see [Does the DalvikVM Garbage Collector halt the whole VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657904/does-the-dalvikvm-garbage-collector-halt-the-whole-vm)

As far as minimizing GC pauses, there does not need to be anything 'memory intensive' as you have described. More often than not, the problem is with creating a lot of smaller objects. The way to minimize GC pause times is to minimize the amount of garbage that you create.

The best way to minimize garbage creation is to pool (re-use) objects rather than creating them, throwing away the reference (allowing the to be GC'd), and then creating another one, etc.

For an approach to doing this, see, for instance,  http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/12/recycling-objects-in-android-with-an-object-pool-to-avoid-garbage-collection